# How to generate a sample of x and y with conditional probability with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to generate a sample of x's and their labels - y's, for binary classifier.

I know that my x's are uniformly distributed in `[0,1]`. But my y's distribution derived by my x's:
`if x in [0.2, 0.4] or in [0.6, 0.8] - P[Y=1] = 0.1`. If x is outside of these bounds then `P[Y=1] = 0.8` .

I think that the best way to do that is by using NumPy (and not using for-loops and if-condition) but until now I didn't succeed.

This is my attempt:

```
s = np.random.uniform(0,1,100) # 100 x samples in [0,1] uniformly distributed
condition  = (np.logical_or((s>0.2)&(s < 0.4), (s>0.6)&(s < 0.8))) # attempt to mark with True the places of x in bounds.
x_in_bounds = np.select(condlist, s) # this line doesn't work
... # how to generate the y values?
```

I am trying unsuccessfully to find a way to randomly generate the y values according to the conditions on the sample of the x values. I'd love to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a solution using your approach see @adnanmuttaleb 's answer.

My approach for this would be using numpy's advanced indexing:

```
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)

cond = ((x > 0.2) & (x < 0.4)) | ((x > 0.6) & (x < 0.8))
not_cond = np.logical_not(cond)

y = np.random.rand(*x.shape)
y[cond] = y[cond] < 0.1
y[not_cond] = y[not_cond] < 0.8
y = y.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to generate two random sequences, filled with either 1 or 0 according to both mentioned cases. Then use `np.where` to select from one or the other depending on `condition`:

```
s = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
condition  = np.logical_or((s>0.2)&(s < 0.4), (s>0.6)&(s < 0.8))

repl_a = (np.random.random(len(s))>0.9).view('i1')
repl_b = (np.random.random(len(s))>0.2).view('i1')

np.where(condition, repl_a, repl_b)

array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the same approach you are using, would be:

```
generate = lambda prob: 1 if np.random.rand() < prob else 0

s = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
low_prob_condition = ((s > 0.2) & (s < 0.4)) | ((s > 0.6) & (s < 0.8))
condlist = [low_prob_condition, np.logical_not(low_prob_condition)] 
labels = np.select(condlist, [[generate(0.1) for _ in range(s.size)], [generate(0.8) for _ in range(s.size)]])

print(labels)
```

Output:

```
[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]
```

But more time and space efficent solution whould be:

```
s = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
low_prob_cond = lambda x: ((x > 0.2) and (x < 0.4)) or ((x > 0.6) and (x < 0.8))
gen = lambda prob: 1 if np.random.rand() < prob else 0
labels = (gen(0.1) if low_prob_cond(x) else gen(0.8) for x in s)

print(list(labels))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

`np.select` requries a list of same size with `s` as choice list for each condition (in your case two), this is obviously can be avoided in your problem.

Comment: Fix typo `genetate` (-> `generate`) in first solution.

Comment: And I think it would be nice to seed the random to prove the solutions are equivalent and produce the same results. Unless the genration order isn't the same and then it's irrelevant...

Comment: @idow09 tnx typo fixed.